# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference (HELP)

Tags: java, android, json, nullpointerexception, response

when i press the call driver button from the rider app. it shows the notifaction at driver app but it crashes because it gives error of invoking a nullpointer error. 
on a null object reference error comes at this line

(JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());)

here is my CustomerCall class

```
private void getDirection(double lat, double lng) {
    String requestAPI = null;
    try{

        requestAPI = "https://maps.googleapis.com/map/api/directions/json?"+
                "mode=driving&"+
                "transit_routing_preference=less_driving&"+
                "origin="+ Common.mLastLocation.getLatitude()+","+Common.mLastLocation.getLongitude()+"&"+
                "destination="+lat+","+lng+"&"+
                "key="+getResources().getString(R.string.google_direction_api);

        Log.d( "Sunny",requestAPI ); //print url for debug

        mService.getPath( requestAPI )
                .enqueue( new Callback<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {

                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
                                JSONArray routes = jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");

                                //after get routes,just get 1st element route
                                JSONObject object = routes.getJSONObject(0);

                                //after get 1st element, we need array with name "legs"
                                JSONArray legs = object.getJSONArray("legs");

                                //and get 1st element of legs array
                                JSONObject legsObject = legs.getJSONObject(0);

                                //Now get Distance
                                JSONObject distance = legsObject.getJSONObject("distance");
                                txtDistance.setText(distance.getString("text"));

                                //get time
                                JSONObject time = legsObject.getJSONObject("duration");
                                txtTime.setText(time.getString("text"));

                                //get address
                                String address = legsObject.getString("end_address");
                                txtAddress.setText(address);


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }



                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText( CustomerCall.this, ""+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

                    }
               } );

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Logcat Error here

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.shk.callingloader, PID: 12668
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.shk.callingloader.CustomerCall$1.onResponse(CustomerCall.java:90)
    at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:71)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Comment: Which is line 90 in CustomerCall.java? Dis your response have a body?

Answer (score 1):

The error message says:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toString()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.shk.callingloader.CustomerCall$1.onResponse(CustomerCall.java:90)
```

I am not sure what on line 90 is but I would say **response.body()** is null and you are calling toString() on it. Add a null check to your method and it should work.

You could pack your code into an if statement:

```
if(response.body() != null){
    //your try-catch block
}
```

or you could return if the body is null:

```
if(response.body() == null){
    return;
}
```

Comment: line 90 is JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());

Comment: Sorry i am new to android can you guide me through the syntax to how to add null check for this.

Comment: That has nothing to do with android. I edited my answer.

Comment: i used this null check. with this way the app is not crashing but still its not showing data when notification comes to driver app and no time, distance and address is shown.

Comment: That means you don't have any data to show in your notification. Your problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
```

try using

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body()); // remove .tostring()
```

Comment: i tried but still it's giving me the same error.

Comment: That means your response.body() is null check for that properly

Comment: can you guide me how? i new to this and i'm facing this problem from past 5 days. i used the null check that AndiCover told but with that way. app is not crashing but no data is shown when the notification comes